# Window or View for the primary nib file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am starting a new project (Empty Application) in Xcode and not using Storyboard.  Now I am onto adding my primary nib file using Xcode's menu "File - New - File" (iOS User Interface selected on the left).

My first question is : Should I use a "Window" or a "View" template for my primary nib file?

On my previous 2 projects I have tried both options.  Both seem to be ok.

Now I am on to my third project.  And I look into the generated code in AppDelegate.m,  an UIWindow object seems to be created by the template code ...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

My second question is : In view of the above method, does that mean that we should not create UIWindow in any nib file because one is already created in code.  (Since there should usually be only one UIWindow in a regular app.)

My last question is : If either UIWindow or UIView is ok, which is the better way ? (In terms of best practice.)

Hope somebody knowledgable could help ...

Comment: This depends basically on the design. My exp with osx is : have one window in mainMenu.xib leave this empty. Create views in this xib or other xibs...and load on the contentViews....

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  But if you have a UIWindow in mainMenu.xib then there shouldn't be any UIWindow created in code.  And the related template code should be deleted.  Am I right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows do not have any visible content themselves but provide a basic container for your application’s views.
 Views define a portion of a window that you want to fill with some content.

Your app should have a UIWindow instance that is the container for the UIView instances you present.
You can load the UIWindow instance from a nib file, or use it programmatically. The main advantage in using through NIB is that you don't need to load everything programmatically .

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, does that mean that if I use a UIWindow nib file, then the template code has to be amended (since it contains statements to create a UIWindow) ?

Comment: Yes if you use UIWindow nib file then delete     self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease]; because it will allocate new instance again.